# Is there a (fast enough) workaround for multiplying matrices exceeding memory limit?

Tags: c++, r, out-of-memory, matrix-multiplication

I have have two distance matrices d_X: n x n and d_Y: m x m.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 2
m <- 3
d_X <- as.matrix(dist(runif(n)))
d_Y <- as.matrix(dist(runif(m)))
```

From matrices d_X and d_Y matrix G: nm x nm is formed:

```
G <- matrix(nrow = n*m,ncol = n*m)
for(i in 1:n) {
      for (j in 1:m) {
            for(ii in 1:n) {
                  for(jj in 1:m) {
                        G[(i-1)*m+j,(ii-1)*m+jj] = abs(d_X[i, ii] - d_Y[j, jj])
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

There is also matrix U: nm*1:

```
U <- runif(m*n)
```

My goal is to calculate `G%*%U`. Now, when `n` and `m` are 200, we need 6GB to allocate `G`. Since `G` is symmetric we could save half the space needed by restoring it properly.

In practice `n` and `m` sizes are up to 5000 which makes allocating G impossible. Since I only need the value of `G%*%U`, it would be sufficient to calculate it piece by piece. I'm struggling to find an effective way to do it.

#### *Time also matters

Since I have to run these calculations thousands of times, it is also important, that computing `G%*%U` takes *reasonable* time. I have used following function to speed up computing `G` in cases where `n` and `m` are less than a hundred:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericMatrix G_mat(NumericMatrix d_X, NumericMatrix d_Y) {
                  NumericMatrix G(d_X.nrow()*d_Y.nrow(),d_X.nrow()*d_Y.nrow());
                  for (int i = 0; i <d_X.nrow(); i++) {
                  for (int j = 0; j < d_Y.nrow(); j++) {
                  for (int ii = 0; ii < d_X.nrow(); ii++) {
                  for (int jj = 0; jj < d_Y.nrow(); jj++) {
                  G(i*d_Y.nrow()+j,ii*d_Y.nrow()+jj) = fabs(d_X(i, ii) - d_Y(j, jj));
                  };
                  };
                  };
                  };
                  return(G);
                  }
                  ')
```

So I guess this workaround should be also implemented in C++ to get best results (speed wise)? How to do it?

Comment: Depending on how much data you're dealing with, you should take a look at SIMD instructions at the very least. With very large datasets (as you've suggested, 6GB... that's quite large). At the very minimum, that allows you to get significant savings just on CPU. You _may also_ benefit from GPU performance; though, in this case (a one-off calculation?) you might not: it might be more expensive to send the data to the GPU and receive result from the GPU than the savings on the GPU could give you. You won't know until you try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this

```
A <- numeric(m*n)
for(i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:n) {
    A[((i-1)*m+1):(i*m)]= A[((i-1)*m+1):(i*m)] + abs(d_Y-d_X[i,j])%*%U[((j-1)*m+1):(j*m)]
  }
}
```